# SQL Query Not Working. Count should return zero also. But not working even after outer join

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am having some trouble to find the solution to this small problem. I wanted to get the count of teams and also I need the zero counts too. This is working if I don't mention specific teams. But failed to work when the query is made complex.

```
SELECT teams.name, COUNT(checkins.team_id) AS "count of checkins"
FROM checkins 
  RIGHT JOIN teams ON checkins.team_id = teams.id
GROUP BY checkins.team_id
```

This failed to work when it is changed like this

```
SELECT teams.name, COUNT(checkins.team_id) AS "count of checkins"
FROM checkins 
  RIGHT JOIN teams ON checkins.team_id = teams.id
  WHERE checkins.team_id IN (1,3,2)
GROUP BY checkins.team_id
```

Comment: Use your Rightmost table for the Where condition since it's on team_id and you'll be good to go: `WHERE teams.id IN (1,3,2)`. If you are wanting all teams from `teams` table then switch that to a `teams LEFT OUTER JOIN checkins` and put the restriction in the ON clause `ON teams.id = checkins.team_id AND checkins.team_id in (1,3,2)`

Comment: Tags conflicting, please correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
SELECT teams.name, COUNT(checkins.team_id) AS "count of checkins"
FROM checkins 
  RIGHT JOIN teams ON checkins.team_id = teams.id
  WHERE (checkins.team_id IN (1,3,2) OR checkins.team_id IS NULL )
GROUP BY checkins.team_id
```

Answer (score 2):

You can move the `WHERE IN ...` condition into the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT
    teams.name,
    COUNT(checkins.team_id) AS "count of checkins"
FROM checkins
RIGHT JOIN teams
    ON checkins.team_id = teams.id AND checkins.team_id IN (1,3,2)
GROUP BY checkins.team_id
```

The reason your latest change is changing the counts is that the `WHERE` clause is filtering off records before the aggregation happens.  By moving everything into the `ON` clause, the join retains all the original records on the right side of the join going into the aggregation.

But most of the time we would write this query using a `LEFT JOIN` rather than a right one:

```
SELECT
    teams.name,
    COUNT(checkins.team_id) AS "count of checkins"
FROM teams
LEFT JOIN checkins
    ON teams.id = checkins.team_id AND checkins.team_id IN (1,3,2)
GROUP BY checkins.team_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works as intended

```
SELECT teams.name, COUNT(checkins.team_id) AS "count of checkins"
FROM checkins 
  RIGHT JOIN teams ON checkins.team_id = teams.id
  WHERE checkins.team_id IN ('1','3','2')
GROUP BY checkins.team_id
```